# How to config Meteor on AWS/EBS using METEOR_SETTINGS environment variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Trying to set up a Meteor on an AWS/EBS (Amazon Web Services, Elastic Beanstalk) environment.

A Meteor dev-run can be passed a command line flag: `--settings settings.json`  where `settings.json`  is a file containing server/client key/value configs (as properly-formatted JSON).

Instead of passing the config file in command line, Meteor's deployment uses a `METEOR_SETTINGS` environment variable. If provided it is expected to contain a json document such as contents of `settings.json`, for example:

```
$ METEOR_SETTINGS=$(cat settings.json)
$ echo $METEOR_SETTINGS
{ "public": { "s3path": "https://d2v4p3rms9rvi3.cloudfront.net" } }
```

The problem is that when I set the value of `METEOR_SETTINGS` to this value in the EBS console:

[image: (screenshot)]

AWS/EBS discards the quotes, escapes the slashes (as seen in screenshot), and sends Meteor:

```
{public:{s3path:https:\/\/d2v4p3rms9rvi3.cloudfront.net}}
```

As indicated by the node start up error:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log
-------------------------------------
npm WARN deprecated backwards-incompatible changes made to `npm run-script` and
npm WARN deprecated semver behavior.

> meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 start /var/app/current
> node main.js


/var/app/current/programs/server/boot.js:283
}).run();
   ^
Error: METEOR_SETTINGS are not valid JSON: {public:{s3path:https:\/\/d2v4p3rms9rvi3.cloudfront.net}}
    at packages/meteor/packages/meteor.js:21:1
    at Package (packages/meteor/packages/meteor.js:42:1)
    at /var/app/current/programs/server/packages/meteor.js:1277:4
    at /var/app/current/programs/server/packages/meteor.js:1286:3
    at /var/app/current/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/var/app/current/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /var/app/current/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
```

Bumping against this problem I tried all sorts of variations for the JSON object in the value field: 
escaping the quotes, enclosing the entire json part with single quotes, replacing double-quotes with single-quotes, and other attempts - neither solved it.

Question is:

How can `METEOR_SETTINGS` be set so that Meteor rcv & parse it correctly?

Note: one of the requirements is that the same build deploys to dev, staging and production environments. Configs need to be set separately for each environment thus if there's another way to inject the settings into the EBS environment w/o modifying the build that will also solve it.

Comment: Can you check this file to see if you can specify env variables there? /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy

Comment: The only other resources I have found are regarding environment variables related to OpWorks apps specifically: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/apps-environment-vars.html or this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.container.html

Comment: As can be seen from screenshot - what is on it is not 1:1 what got delivered into Meteor. So I would expect that there is some magic happening and you would be able to somehow specify it correctly. My 1st try would be something like

`testJSON = { "public": { "s3path": "https://d2v4p3rms9rvi3.cloudfront.net" } };`
`var temp = JSON.stringify(testJSON);`
`var result = encodeURIComponent(temp);`
`console.log(temp);`
{"public":{"s3path":"https://d2v4p3rms9rvi3.cloudfront.net"}}
`console.log(result);`
%7B%22public%22%3A%7B%22s3path%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fd2v4p3rms9rvi3.cloudfront.net%22%7D%7D

Comment: @RobertSimon not sure I follow what exactly you mean, but indeed using `encodeURIComponent` is useful. It will not help with `METEOR_SETTINGS` because meteor does not expect it to be url encoded, but it could fit with the 2nd workaround I mentioned: if that workaround is in place, one can set a `METEOR_SETTINGS_ENCODED` env variable with the url-encoded json. Then, have it decoded and populate `Meteor.settings` in the `Meteor.startup()` section. It's still a hack, but at least it provides a path to programmatically populate `Meteor.settings` from a `settings.json` file on aws/ebs

Comment: Meteor does not expect it to be encoded URL, but there is some visible decoding between the value on screenshot and what Meteor got. So I would think that providing some encoded/correctly_escaped string on the web could end up as valid JSON string served to meteor. What would meteor receive if you follow my steps of getting encodeURIComponent value of that object and paste it to form on web?

Answer (score 3):

After discussing this issue with AWS support I realized that AWS/EBS does not support storing JSON in environment variables. This is because the environment variables are stored as key/value strings in unencoded JSON (apparently, in CloudFormation). The bottom line here a bit disappointing:

## METEOR_SETTINGS cannot be used in the AWS/EBS console

This is indeed unfortunate, however there are a couple of workarounds.

#### 1st Workaround

Move the json configs into an s3 bucket and place the following content in a `.ebextensions/app.config` file:

```
container_commands: 
  01_setvariable: 
    command: "aws s3 cp s3://<bucket-name>/nodejs.conf /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#init#nodejs.conf
```

This will entirely override `/etc/init/nodejs.conf` with content retrieved from your s3 bucket. Naturally there's an opportunity to set/override individual settings using fine-tuned/fancy bash scripting.

*I ended up not choosing this method, because it involves another entity (an S3 bucket) and the dev iteration requires a new version deploy, which isn't terribly fast.*

#### 2nd Workaround

*Note: this is a simple code-hack I came up with. It seems to put all this mess behind while not requiring much effort.*

My original need was to propagate AWS/EBS env vars to the client, so I decided to bypass the `METEOR_SETTINGS` variable and populate `Meteor.settings.public` directly with env vars from node's `process.env` space. The whitelisting is managed by a simple list. Add a `server/lib/config.js` file with:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    // public settings that need to be exposed to the client can be added here
    var publicEnvs = {
        S3_PATH: 's3path'
    };
    var modified;
    _.each(publicEnvs, (value, key) => {
        let envValue = process.env[key];
        if (envValue) {
            Meteor.settings.public[value] = envValue;
            modified = true;
        }
    });
    if (modified) {
        __meteor_runtime_config__.PUBLIC_SETTINGS = Meteor.settings.public;
    }
});
```

Hurray, your client can access the env vars of your choice!

For example with this change, an S3_PATH environment variable defined in the EBS console can be accessed as `Meteor.settings.public.s3path` on the client. Quite simple, and without many moving parts :)

Comment: The only problem of the 2º workaround is that then you cannot use your settings in the root /lib since it's the first directory to load. I reported this bug to amazon: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=236405&tstart=0

Comment: In such case, what if the code were to be placed under root /lib, so that it loads before everything else e.g. under `/lib/lib/config.js`?

Answer (score 2):

Tested another workaround.

after `meteor build --directory`
edit `main.js` as following

```
process.argv.splice(2, 0, 'program.json');
var settingfilename = './settings.json';
if (process.env.METEOR_SETTING_FILE)
  settingfilename = process.env.METEOR_SETTING_FILE;
var settings = require(settingfilename);
if (settings) {
  try {
    process.env.METEOR_SETTINGS = JSON.stringify(settings);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
process.chdir(require('path').join(__dirname, 'programs', 'server'));
require('./programs/server/boot.js');
```

and copy `settings.json` into `bundle/` and `eb init` and `eb deploy`.

you can set the other settings file with adding `METEOR_SETTING_FILE` at Environment Properties in Configuration tab from EB Console.

editing file is needed after every build.

---

added the patch file to use in the build script like `ed - ../build/bundle/main.js < main.js.patch`

main.js.patch

```
8a
var settingfilename = './settings.json';
if (process.env.METEOR_SETTING_FILE)
  settingfilename = process.env.METEOR_SETTING_FILE;
var settings = require(settingfilename);
if (settings) {
  try {
    process.env.METEOR_SETTINGS = JSON.stringify(settings);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
// console.log (JSON.stringify(process.env));
.
w
```

Comment: @AdrianLopez thanks for your reply. Unless I am missing something, your suggestion involves changing the build thus does not answer the question which specifies that: "the requirements is that the same build deploys to dev, staging and production environments. Configs need to be set separately for each environment".

Comment: you can use the same build. as I mentioned before, by setting `METEOR_SETTING_FILE` as `./settings.dev.json` in environment variable. I have `ed - ../build/bundle/main.js < main.js.patch` in the build script. I've added the patch file above

Comment: Still, the solution you suggested requires all configuration (secret keys, etc) for all deployments (dev, staging, production) to be in the repository. This violates the separation between code and configuration and is typically discouraged due to the (obvious) security implications involved

Comment: @tivoni,  I agree with your perspective. but I had many settings in the `settings.json`. if it is not too long, I wouldn't copy my `settings.json` into the deployment. I would add some code to parse json string from METEOR_SETTINGS variables rather than load json file.

Answer (score 1):

**NEW SOLUTION**

This is thet easier way I'm able to come with. I've made a bash script that automatically generates a compressed build of your project and integrates the settings file so you don't really have to do anything.

**BEFORE TO RUN THIS SCRIPT**

In your meteor project create ./lib/beanstalk-settings-fix.js

```js
/*==============================================================================
 * Globals
 *============================================================================*/
/*global process*/
/*global Meteor*/
/*global Npm*/


if (Meteor.isProduction){
  var meteorFile = process.env.METEOR_SETTINGS_FILE;
  if(meteorFile == undefined) throw new Error(
    'METEOR_SETTINGS_FILE env variable must be defined in production.')
  var fs = Npm.require('fs');
  var pjsonBuf = fs.readFileSync( meteorFile );
  Meteor.settings = JSON.parse( pjsonBuf.toString().trim());
}
```

**HOW TO USE IT**

1. Copy the next code to a text file and save it as build.sh
2. Edit the constants.
3. Give it execution permissions and run it.

You'll end with something like project-name.zip ready to upload it to your beanstalk environment. I hope you find it useful!

This solution is based on [AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=236405&tstart=0). If you want to check the old solutions, please check the edit history.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#===============================================================================
# DESCRIPTION:
#===============================================================================
# This script creates a build of the project ready to be uploaded to beanstalk.
# Requires pyton 2.7.x

#===============================================================================
# COMMON ISSUES:
#===============================================================================
# -If you upload the output to a sample application, it will fail.
# -Version format must be 0.0.0

#===============================================================================
# CONSTANTS
#===============================================================================
CURRENT_VERSION="1.0.0"
OUTPUT_NAME="file-name-without-extension"
PRODUCTION_SETTINGS_JSON="./your-project-directory/settings-prod.json"
PROJECT_DIRECTORY="./your-project-directory"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY="./the-output-directory"
ROOT_URL="http://www.SOMEENVIRONMENT-env.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
MONGO_URL="none"

#===============================================================================
# SAY HELLO
#===============================================================================
initial_directory=$(pwd)  #  This file's local path
clear
echo "COOKING OUTPUT"
echo "========================================================="

#===============================================================================
# RAW PROJECT BUILD
#===============================================================================
echo "> BUILDING RAW PROJECT"
cd $initial_directory
cd $PROJECT_DIRECTORY
rm -f -R "../build/bundle"
meteor build --directory ../build/

#===============================================================================
# SET PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
#===============================================================================
cd $initial_directory
json=`cat $PRODUCTION_SETTINGS_JSON`
cd $OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/bundle
mkdir -p .ebextensions
echo "option_settings:" >> .ebextensions/environment.config
echo "  - option_name: MONGO_URL" >> .ebextensions/environment.config
echo "    value: $MONGO_URL" >> .ebextensions/environment.config
echo "option_settings:" >> .ebextensions/environment.config
echo "  - option_name: ROOT_URL" >> .ebextensions/environment.config
echo "    value: "$ROOT_URL"" >> .ebextensions/environment.config
echo "files:" >> .ebextensions/environment.config
echo " '/tmp/settings.json':" >> .ebextensions/environment.config
echo "    content : |" >> .ebextensions/environment.config
echo "        "$json >> .ebextensions/environment.config
echo "option_settings:" >> .ebextensions/environment.config
echo "  - namespace:  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment" >> .ebextensions/environment.config
echo "    option_name: METEOR_SETTINGS_FILE" >> .ebextensions/environment.config
echo "    value: '/tmp/settings.json'" >> .ebextensions/environment.config
chmod 444 .ebextensions/environment.config
echo "> ADDING 'settings.json' AS ENV VAR"

#===============================================================================
# CREATE PACKAGE.JSON
#===============================================================================
cd $initial_directory
cd $OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/bundle

# Write base package.json
echo '{
  "name": "'$OUTPUT_NAME'",
  "version": "'$CURRENT_VERSION'",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node main.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
}' > ./package.json

# Add dependencies from meteor in packages.json
# Then add extra dependencies defined by us.
EXTRA_DEPENDENCIES='{"forever": "*"}'
meteor_packages=$(cat ./programs/server/package.json)
packages=$(cat ./package.json)
packages_updated=`python <<END
import json;
# We cannot operate directly bash variables, so we make a copy.
a = $packages
b = $meteor_packages
a['dependencies'] = b['dependencies']
for key, value in $EXTRA_DEPENDENCIES.iteritems():
    a['dependencies'].update({key: value})
print json.dumps(a, sort_keys=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '));
END`
echo "$packages_updated" > ./package.json
chmod 444 ./package.json
echo "> ADDING 'package.json'"

#===============================================================================
# ZIP OUTPUT
#===============================================================================
cd $initial_directory
cd $OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/bundle
zip -FSrq "../$OUTPUT_NAME-$CURRENT_VERSION.zip" .
echo "> ZIP THE OUTPUT"

#===============================================================================
# CLEAN THE HOUSE
#===============================================================================
cd $initial_directory
cd $OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
rm -R -f ./bundle
echo "> CLEAN THE HOUSE"

#===============================================================================
# SAY GOODBYE
#===============================================================================
echo "========================================================="
echo "YOU CAN UPLOAD THE PROJECT TO A BEANSTALK ENVIRONMENT NOW"
```

**Some extra help:** In case you want to check that everything went fine, you can find your final settings in your zipped output, under /.ebextensions/environment.config and your packages file under /package.json

Comment: I am getting the following error on the client:

Uncaught Error: METEOR_SETTINGS_FILE env variable must be defined in production.

I have configured step 1 as mentioned. My settings file has public, private and kadira objects. However when I do `Meteor.settings.public` in the browser, it gives me an empty object even though `/tmp/settings.json` has multiple keys

Comment: I didn't updated the solution yet because I didn't had a chance test it on production but you migh find it useful. [I've made an script that automatically produces a compressed build of your project](http://pastebin.com/2tNz8nx7) that you can upload to beanstalk. You only have to open it, edit the constants. Give it execution permissions and run it.

Comment: As you mentioned, step one still needs to be done manually, correct? I will try now and let you know if that works. I think the environment variable for METEOR_SETTINGS_FILE isn't available on the since if I do `process.env` in the console, I don't see it.

Comment: I managed to make that solution work but it wasn't very intuitive or elegant. I recommend you the new one. Post updated.

Comment: I uploaded the bundle, however getting a 502 Nginx error. Could you share your nginx configuration? or is it within .ebextensions ?

Comment: I recommend you to check the logs from  beanstalk, nginx, meteor and mongodb. In my case the problem was in the database. Please tell us if you solve it.

Comment: Nodejs logs suggest that Meteor settings aren't defined when using the configuration file linked above. I have my `METEOR_SETTINGS_FILE` in my env variables however, if I don't use the `eb_fix.js` file you created earlier, how do those settings get populated to `Meteor.settings`

Comment: Added the file, `Uncaught Error: METEOR_SETTINGS_FILE env variable must be defined in production.` Environment variables from the EB config don't make it to the client I guess. 

Probably because when I console log `process.env` i get the following

    Object
      NODE_ENV: "production"
      TEST_METADATA: "{}"

Comment: It worked for me, if I recall correctly. Try asking in [AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=236405&tstart=0) if the content of /.ebextensions/environment.config is correct. That file is meant to create the METEOR_SETTINGS_FILE environment variable.

Comment: It does, I can see it in my console. However, as far as I know, env variables are only accessible on the server since they usually store some security keys and configs that are used to set up the server. That's why none of them get passed down to the client. I am not sure how to proceed at this point, will try to keep digging and getting it figured out with their support

Comment: If you read /.ebextensions/environment.config you'll see that when you upload your project to beanstalk, it's crating the file /tmp/settings.json wich contain your settings. Also, it's creating the ENV variable METEOR_SETTINGS_FILE, wich is just the path to this file. The file beanstalk-settings-fix.js will load the content of this file, and that's all. Since the server serves the website to the client, you'll have your public settings in the client. I hope I explained clearly. I'm glad at least you were able to run your environment without errors (I think).