# How to set path for GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a SpringBoot project where I'm using firebase authentication, `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` Environment variable set in my local machine to the path of json file that I downloaded from Google Cloud console.

But now I'm deploying app (jar) to Elastic Beanstalk but I'm not sure how to setup that path there and where to place this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the workaround, I placed my google credentials file (firebase-server-config.json) in spring-boot project path /src/main/resources/ and provide credentials by reading file stream.

```
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public void initFirebase() throws IOException {
        FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder().setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("firebase-server-config.json"))).build();
        if (FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) {
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        }
    }
```

pom.xml dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Could you please accept your answer? In this way the community members can identify easily the solution to the question.

Comment: @JossBaron, sure, i'll do that as right now it is not allowing me to do it and saying that 'You can mark it after 9 hours'.. Thanks for guidance.

Comment: This worked for me. It likely seems that using S3 method is the more elegant way to go given the limitation, but so frustrating that it is not straight forward in AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and that the Environmental Properties don't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following steps if you don't want to store the credentials as part of the code base:

1. Download the service account credentials JSON file from Google Cloud.
2. Get encoded string from the JSON file
   For base64 encoding, you can use one of the online utilities or system commands to do that. For Linux and Mac, you can use base64 <<service_account_json_file>> to print the file contents as a base64-encoded string.
3. On the Secrets Manager console, choose Store a new secret.
4. For Secret type, select Other type of secret.
5. Enter your key as credentials and the value as the base64-encoded string.
6. Leave the rest of the options at their default.
7. Choose Next.
8. Give a name to the secret bigquery_credentials.
9. Follow through the rest of the steps to store the secret.

Here is link for the complete instructions:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/migrating-data-from-google-bigquery-to-amazon-s3-using-aws-glue-custom-connectors/

Answer (score 0):

I guess Elastic Beanstalk still doesn't support JSON values in environment variables. Furthermore, keeping credentials in environment variables can be dangerous if another user with access to EBS can see the credentials.

There is a similar question asked and some workarounds shared here: [How to config Meteor on AWS/EBS using METEOR_SETTINGS environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761577/how-to-config-meteor-on-aws-ebs-using-meteor-settings-environment-variable)

One of the suggested ways by Amazon is storing the JSON file in an s3 bucket and downloading it from the bucket at the deployment phase with a configuration.
There is a very suitable [solution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/rds-external-credentials.html) provided by Amazon for using an external JSON file for storing credentials to be used in EBS